# parsing .log files then sort in access

Tags: python, excel, ms-access

I'm writing a parsing program that that searches through 100+ .log files after some keyword, then puts the words in different array´s and separates the words in to columns in excel. Now I want to sort them in Access automatically so that I can process the different .log file combinations. I can "copy paste" from my Excel file to Access, but that so inefficient and gives some errors... I would like it to be "automatic". I'm new to Access and don´t know how to link from python to Access, I have tried doing it as I did to Excel but that didn't work and started looking in to OBDC but had some problems there to...

```
import glob   # includes
import xlwt  # includes
from os import listdir  # includes
from os.path import isfile, join    # includes


def logfile(filename, tester, createdate,completeresponse):
    # Arrays for strings
    response = []
    message = []
    test = []
    date = []

    with open(filename) as filesearch:   # open search file
        filesearch = filesearch.readlines()   # read file

    for line in filesearch:
        file = filename[39:]    # extract filename [file]
        for lines in filesearch:
            if createdate in lines:   # extract "Create Time" {date}
                date.append(lines[15:34])
            if completeresponse in lines:
                response.append(lines[19:])

        print('pending...')

        i = 1   # set a number on log {i}
        d = {}
        for name in filename:
            if not d.get(name, False):
                d[name] = i
                i += 1

        if tester in line:
            start = '-> '
            end = ':\ '                                                     #  |<----------->|
            number = line[line.find(start)+3: line.find(end)]        #Tester -> 1631 22 F1 2E :\ BCM_APP_31381140 AJ \ Read Data By Identifier \
            test.append(number)   # extract tester {test}
                                                                    #              |<--------------------------------------------
            text = line[line.find(end)+3:]             # Tester -> 1631 22 F1 2E :\ BCM_APP_31381140 AJ \ Read Data By Identifier \
            message.append(text)

    with open('Excel.txt', 'a') as handler:  # create .txt file
        for i in range(len(message)):
            #                  A       B      C     D           E
            handler.write(f"{file}|{date[i]}|{i}|{test[i]}|{response[i]}")
        # A = filename  B = create time  C = number in file  D = tester   E = Complete response

# open with 'w' to "reset" the file.
with open('Excel.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    pass
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Access\*.log'):
    logfile(filename, 'Sending Request: Tester ->', 'Create Time:','Complete Response:','Channel')


def if_number(s):   # look if number or float
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
# ----------------------------------------------

my_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Access"  # directory
# search directory for .txt files
text_files = [join(my_path, f) for f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, f)) and '.txt' in f]

for text_file in text_files:     # loop and open .txt document
    with open(text_file, 'r+') as wordlist:
        string = []  # array ot the saved string
        for word in wordlist:
            string.append(word.split('|'))   # put word to string array
        column_list = zip(*string)  # make list of all string

    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Tab')
    worksheet.col(0)    # construct cell
    first_col = worksheet.col(0)
    first_col.width = 256*50

    second_col = worksheet.col(1)
    second_col.width = 256*25
    third_col = worksheet.col(2)
    third_col.width = 256*10
    fourth_col = worksheet.col(3)
    fourth_col.width = 256*50
    fifth_col = worksheet.col(4)
    fifth_col.width = 256*100

    i = 0   # choose column 0 = A, 3 = C etc
    for column in column_list:

        for item in range(len(column)):
            value = column[item].strip()
            if if_number(value):

                worksheet.write(item, i, float(value))  # text / float
            else:
                worksheet.write(item, i, value)  # number / int
        i += 1

print('File:', text_files, 'Done')

workbook.save(text_file.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

[image]

Is there a way to automate the "copy paste"-command, if so how would that look like and work? and if that's something that can´t be done, some advice would help a lot!

EDIT

Thanks i have done som googling and thanks for your help! but now i get a a error... i still can´t send the information to the Access file, i get a syntax error. and i know it exist because i would want to uppdate the existing file... is there a command to "uppdate an exising Acces file"?

**error**

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Table 'tblLogfile' already exists. (-1303) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

**code**

```
import pyodbc


UDC = r'C:\Users\Documents\Access\UDC.accdb'
# DSN Connection
constr = " DSN=MS Access Database; DBQ={0};".format(UDC)
# DRIVER connection
constr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/USERS/DOCUMENTS/ACCESS;DBQ=C:/USERS/DOCUMENTS/ACCESS/UDC.accdb"

# Connect to database UDC and open cursor
db = pyodbc.connect(constr)
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * INTO [tblLogfile]" +\
      "FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:/Users/Documents/Access/Excel.xls.[Tab];"

cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: You can use the answer provided by @vince-west but really PyODBC is the way to go. The whole copy-pasting to the clipboard to transfer data is really inefficient compared to just using database calls, and if your previous attempt using Excel failed, I doubt you will succeed through this approach. If you have trouble using PyODBC, you can always ask a question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note, MS Access, a database management system, is not MS Excel, a spreadsheet application. Access sits on top of a relational engine and maintains strict rules in data and relational integrity whereas in Excel anything can be written across cells or ranges of cells with no rules. Additionally, the Access object library (tabledefs, querydefs, forms, reports, macros, modules) is much different than the Excel object library (workbooks, worksheets, range, cell, etc.), so there is no one-to-one translation in code.

Specifically, for your Python project, consider *pyodbc* using a make-table query that runs a direct connection to the Excel workbook. Since MS Access' database is the ACE/JET engine (Windows .dll files, available on Windows machines regardless of Access install). One feature of this data store is the ability to connect to workbooks even text files! So really, MSAccess.exe is just a GUI console to view .mdb/.accdb files.

Below creates a new database table that replicates the specific workbook sheet data, assuming the sheet maintains:

1. tabular format beginning in `A1` cell (no merged cells/repeating labels)
2. headers in top row (no spaces before or after or special characters `!#$%^~<>))`)
3. columns of consistent data type format (i.e., data integrity rules)

Python code

```
import pyodbc

databasename = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File.accdb'

# DSN Connection
constr = "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ={0};".format(databasename)    
# DRIVER CONNECTION
constr = "DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={0};".format(databasename)

# CONNECT TO DATABASE AND OPEN CURSOR
db = pyodbc.connect(constr)
cur = db.cursor()

# RUN MAKE-TABLE QUERY FROM EXCEL WORKBOOK SOURCE
# OLDER EXCEL FORMAT
sql = "SELECT * INTO [myNewTable]" + \
      " FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xls].[SheetName$];"

# CURRENT EXCEL FORMAT
sql = "SELECT * INTO [myNewTable]" + \
      " FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx].[SheetName$];"

cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()

cur.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: @Parfati Thanks!! :), i have a follow upp question if you have time to help, look edit

Answer (score 0):

***Almost certainly the answer from Parfait above is a better way to go, but for fun I'll leave my answer below***

---

If you are willing to put in the time I think you need 3 things to complete the automation of what you want to do:

1) Send a string representation of your data to the windows Clipboard 
There is windows specific code for this, or you can just save yourself some time and use [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip)

2) Learn VBA and use VBA to grab the string from the clipboard and process it.  Here is some example VBA code that I used in excel the past to grab text from the Clipboard

```
Function GetTextFromClipBoard() As String
    Dim MSForms_DataObject As New MSForms.DataObject
    MSForms_DataObject.GetFromClipboard
    GetTextFromClipBoard = MSForms_DataObject.GetText()
End Function
```

3) use [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) (I believe available easily with Anaconda) to automate the vba access calls from Python.  This is probably going to be the hardest part as the specific call trees are (in my opinion) not well documented and takes a lot of poking and digging to figure out what exactly you need to do.  Its painful to say the least, but use IPython to help you with visual cues of what methods your pywin32 objects have available.

As I look at the instructions above, I realize it may also be possible to skip the clipboard and just send the information directly from python to access via pywin32.  If you do the clipboard route however, you can break the steps up.

1. send one dataset to the clipboard
2. grab and process the data [using the VBA editor in Access](http://www.accessallinone.com/opening-the-vba-editor/)
3. after you figure out 1 and 2, use pywin32 to bridge the gap

Good luck, and maybe write a blog post about it if you figure it out to share the details.